# Dismissing view controller does not goes back to the previous view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I am presenting a view controller after pushing another view controller with animation as my application requires it. The code is as given below:

```
    func pushViewController() {
    let viewcontroller = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeSearchIndentifier") as? HomeSearchViewController
    let searchViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "searchRideIdentifier") as? SearchRideViewController
    searchViewController?.parentView = .homeLandingPage
    let duration = 0.4
    let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = duration
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
    self.navigationController!.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller!, animated: false)
    viewcontroller?.present(searchViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

In the presented view controller i am assigning a Side Menu controller as i need to show the side menu while swiping to the right:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.addSearchListScreen()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    yourLocation.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(7, 0, 0)
    let leftViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "SideBar", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sideBar") as? SideBarViewController
    let slideMenuController = SlideMenuTrackerController(mainViewController: self, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController!)
    AppDelegate.sharedInstance().window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
    leftViewController?.mainViewController = self
    slideMenuController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
    AppDelegate.sharedInstance().window?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 236.0, green: 238.0, blue: 241.0, alpha: 1.0)
    AppDelegate.sharedInstance().window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
  }
```

Now i have a custom back button in this view controller. On clicking it i need to dismiss the view controller and show the view controller from where it was presented . The name is "HomeSearchViewController"

For dismissing i wrote the following code in the button action:

```
    func navigateToPreviousController() {
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

But this is not dismissing the view controller. May i know what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** My first answer addressed only part of the problem.

Looking further at your code...

It appears you are **pushing** `HomeSearchViewController` onto the `navigationController` stack, and then also **presenting** `SearchRideViewController` from `HomeSearchViewController`.

However...

In:

```
HomeSearchViewController viewDidLoad()
```

you create an instance of

```
SideBarViewController (leftViewController)
```

and you create an instance of

```
SlideMenuTrackerController (slideMenuController)
```

and assign

```
self as the .mainViewController and
leftViewController as the .leftMenuViewController
of slideMenuController.
```

If that's not confusing enough, you also:

```
AppDelegate.sharedInstance().window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
```

which ***replaces*** `HomeSearchViewController` ... which you had just pushed  onto the `navigationController` stack!

So, your view hierarchy is now (or, at least, seems to be if I am following your code):

```
Window
    slideMenuController (instance of SlideMenuTrackerController)
        +- searchViewController (instance of SearchRideViewController)
        +- leftViewController (instance of SideBarViewController)
```

In order to "get back to" where you came from, you will need to re-create whatever VC you want to get to and (again) replace `AppDelegate.sharedInstance().window?.rootViewController`.

Without seeing your entire project, I'm not sure how you should really go about that.

---

*[original answer]*

In here:

```
func pushViewController() {
    // ... the other lines
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller!, animated: false)
    viewcontroller?.present(searchViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

You **push** `viewcontroller` and also `.present(searchViewController!...` *from* `viewcontroller` (that's a bit odd to begin with, but regardless)...

Then in here:

```
func navigateToPreviousController() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You `.dismiss` a view controller, but you never `.pop` back on the navigation controller's stack.

Comment: So what i need to do now?

Comment: do you mean to replace dismiss with pop?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `UINavigationController.popViewController(animated: Bool)`.

Comment: but i don't have any navigation controller in the present view controller

Comment: it would be a great help if you post the code in your answer dear :)

Comment: Is the `viewDidLoad()` function in your question part of `SearchRideViewController`?

Comment: @ChelseaShawra - see my edits... not sure how helpful this will be, but maybe with the way you've designed the navigation in your app this will start to make sense.

Comment: okk i understood . So how to recreate the vie controller and where to create it. I was able to understand what you conveyed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155360/discussion-between-chelsea-shawra-and-donmag).

Answer (score 0):

in order to dismiss the view controller your view controller should be embedded inside a navigation controller.

eg:

```
let controller =storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardidentifier") as! yourviewcontroller        
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and then on the presented view controller if you use below code it will dismiss the view controller.

```
func dismissButtonPressed(){
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Cheers!!